# Display match found or not using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

i have a scenario 
where i have three words in a file called demo.txt

My three words are  : apple , mango , grapes

i want to write a one linear command to check if all three word exist in a file then display match found successfully or otherwise display match not found

how to do with awk command in one linear way

below is my code not working

```
awk '{print (/apple/|/mango/|/grapes/ ? "true : match found " : "false : not found ")}' /D/demo.txt
```

**sample file : demo.txt**

```
abc:apple
b:mango
fgg:grapes
ball , candle 
vik,mani
raj,vilas
```

apart from first file **i have second file which contain below text

```
Azr
hjkds
$$ABC=%wkde**mo
$Bilas=%ram 
xyz
vxbnx
ram
```

I want to check whether the exact keyword present or not 
    $$ABC=%wkde**mo
    $Bilas=%ram

if match found display message keyword found or otherwise display keyword not found

Comment: [You really need `awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? `grep -E "apple|mango|grapes" 080_sin080a.txt && echo "found" || echo "not found"`?

Comment: @PabloA that checks if either of the three words are present, whereas OP is asking if input contains all three words

Comment: Please, for testing give a sample file. Will partial matches suffice, ie. _grapes_ ~ _grapeseed_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following. In case your awk supports word boundaries.

```
awk '
/\<apple\>/{
  app_found=1
}
/\<mango\>/{
  mango_found=1
}
/\<grapes\>/{
  grapes_found=1
}
END{
  if(app_found && mango_found && grapes_found){
    print "All 3 words found."
  }
  else{
    print "All 3 words are NOT present in whole Input_file."
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: i have posted sample file on question please check

Comment: @rarkatatruenayu, ok sure please check my edited solution now and let me know?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 everything is fine. I misunderstood the question. I thought OP wants the "line" to contain the three words.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the code is perfect as expected … can it be little modified like passing multiple keywords like |apple|mango|grapes  …. the code works for 3 keywords for suppose if i need to check 10 keywords then the code need to change their is no reusability … always the code need to change manually

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 even the code does not output the value if the keyword is found please write the code in such a way that it can be reusable if i add multiple keywords can you help me with the code …by providing the better solution

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hi can you please look at the question above i have added another text file below first text file in that the entire sentence need to be matched if it is found then should display match found otherwise display not not found … can you work with second file data … the above code works perfect with first file it should work with second file also this is challenging question for me i am not able to implement using using awk script which you provided can you help me to match the keyword which i mentioned in the question

Comment: @rarkatatruenayu, In my humble opinion, one post one question only please(else future users/readers will be confused), request you to please open new question for same, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited answer:** the following command has been tested with the input sample provided above and works as desired:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { RS = "§" }
  {print (/apple/ && /mango/&&/grapes/) ? "match found" : "match not found"}
' demo.txt
```

I used the char `§` as record separator because there is no such a char in the input and because `RS = "\0"` is not portable. If you feel it could happen that such a `§` could occur in the input file, you can use the portable solution below:

```
awk '
  { i = i $0 } 
  END { print (i ~ /apple/ && i ~ /mango/ && i ~ /grapes/) ? "match found" : "match not found"}
' demo.txt
```

Comment: @Sundeep: if the OP really wants to match across lines, which I can't deduce from his awk snippet, he can change the record separator `RS` to something else than `\n`.

Comment: @Sundeep: since the OP made his intention clear, I edited my script in order to make it work across multiple lines.

Comment: cool... however, I think OP doesn't want partial match based on other comments and empty RS means paragraph mode, it will not slurp entire file as single string

Comment: @Sundeep: Yu are right and I learnt something new. I changed `RS = ""` into `RS="\0"` which seems to work, even with several paragraphs.

Comment: @Sundeep: it seems that the construction `RS="\0"` is not portable. I will put another char that doesn't appear in the input, as v.gr. `§`.

Comment: Don't pick some random char you hope won't be in the input, just do the portable solution (put pick a better name than the often-used `i`, e.g. `rec`, for the record). It should be  `{ rec = (NR>1 ? rec ORS : "") $0 }` to create the record though, not just `{ rec = rec $0 }` as the direct concatenation across input lines in the latter will create strings that didn't appear in the input.

Comment: To see what I mean about the concatenation, try adding `big man` as one input line and then `go fish` on the next line and then searching for `mango` - it'd match because `rec = rec $0` would create `big mango fish` (which sounds delicious but is probably undesirable outside of a restaurant context :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

WIth GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='^$' '
    { f = (/apple/ && /mango/ && /grapes/) }
    END { print (f ? "true : match found " : "false : not found "); exit !f }
' /D/demo.txt
```

or if you don't want to accept partial matches then adding word boundaries:

```
awk -v RS='^$' '
    { f = (/\<apple\>/ && /\<mango\>/ && /\<grapes\>/) }
    END { print (f ? "true : match found " : "false : not found "); exit !f }
' /D/demo.txt
```

You need to do the print in the `END` section rather than while processing the input to properly handle empty files and the `exit` ensures you'll behave the same as grep in setting a success exit status when the match succeeds, fail otherwise.

With any awk you could do:

```
awk '
    { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    END {
        $0 = ORS rec
        f = (/[^[:alnum:]_]apple[^[:alnum:]_]/ && /[^[:alnum:]_]mango[^[:alnum:]_]/ && /[^[:alnum:]_]grapes[^[:alnum:]_]/)
        print (f ? "true : match found " : "false : not found ")
        exit !f
    }
' /D/demo.txt
```

or if you don't want to read the whole file into memory at once then also with any awk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { numTgts = split("apple mango pears",words) }
    {
        for (i in words) {
            word = words[i]
            if ( (FS $0 FS) ~ ("[^[:alnum:]_]" word "[^[:alnum:]_]") ) {
                if ( ++numHits == numTgts ) {
                    f = 1
                    exit
                }
                delete words[i]
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        print (f ? "true : match found " : "false : not found ")
        exit !f
    }
' /D/demo.txt
```

or for string instead of regexp comparisons (which all of the above use):

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        numTgts = split("apple mango pears",tmp)
        for (i in tmp) {
            words[tmp[i]]
        }
        FS = "[^[:alnum:]_]+"
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            word = $i
            if (word in words) {
                if ( ++numHits == numTgts ) {
                    f = 1
                    exit
                }
                delete words[word]
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        print (f ? "true : match found " : "false : not found ")
        exit !f
    }
' /D/demo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another that reads words from the `demo` file, hashes them into `a` hash, counts the matches and if for any match word there wasn't a match, `print`s `false`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {           # read and process demo
    split($0,t,/ *, */)    # split by comma and spaces, if any to a temp array
    for(i in t)            # make another array with match words as keys
        a[t[i]]
    next
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)     # iterate all space separated words in the file
        if($i in a)
            a[$i]++        # count match words in  it
}
END {                      # in the end
    for(i in a)
        if(!a[i]) {        # if there was a match word that had no matches
            print "false"  # print false
            exit           # and exit
        }
    print "true"           # else all match words matched in the file
}' demo file
```

Output is either `true` or `false`.

**Update:** As in your sample file the match words are found colon attached to other strings, the solution will not match per se. You need to modify the main loop above to:

```
{
    n=split($0,t,/[^a-zA-Z]+/) # split by all non-alphabetical chars
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)          # iterate all words in the array t
        if(t[i] in a)
            a[t[i]]++          # count match words in it
}
```

It will split the lines by all non-alphabetical charactes (`[^a-zA-Z]`) and consider those substrings as words. Modify that regex to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Perl can be handy

```
$ perl -0777 -ne  ' if( /apple/ && /mango/ && /grapes/ ) { print "Found\n" } else { print "not found\n" }  ' demo.txt
Found
$
```